# Table not coming in proper format in SSRS

Tags: reporting-services, page-break

I have 4 tables and each table has hidden expression. I need to start each table from new page. I applied page break at end of tables but it didn't take any effect. Then I placed these 4 tables in 4 rectangles and applied page break at end of rectangles. It works fine and every table starts from new page, but now the issue is if any table has no data than there is blank page in report.

Answer (score 0):

Find Answer:-
Actually report width and body width was not right.
Always remember that ReportWidth-LeftMargin-RightMargin > BodyWidth